# Blackberry: Using Observer Pattern

Tags: eclipse, list, blackberry, java-me

I am doing a project that displays news in a List Field. The news is returned in an XML from a web service. Being new in Java for blackberry I have made some progress by browsing, researching and asking questions.

I have been able to

1. fetch the xml returned from the web service
2. parse the xml through a DOM/SAX parser
3. add the data to a vector
4. and display the data using a List Field

Problem: How do i update the List Field with new or current news (data) assuming a user is currently viewing or scrolling through the list without him being aware or knowing.

Suggestion: From my little research, I discovered that this can be achieved using Observer Pattern. How? Sample code or snippet if possible.

Comment: Yes, but it is not making sense. I am kindda confused on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Observer Pattern would only make sense if you had a way to listen for changes in your remote data (i.e.: if your server delivered a push message to the BB when data changes). Since you have to pull data, you are not listening anything, what you need is just to update the list after each WS call.

To update the list, have a look at the methods in [`ObjectListField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html) class. You can insert and delete single rows. To update single or several rows you have to set the entire array. After the modification, just call invalidate on the field.

Answer (score -1):

In Java library you can find Observer interface and Observable class. Made the object you want to observe (in this case the listField) inherits the Observable class. Then create a class that implements the Observer interface, this class it's the one who gonna update your data. More: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html

The thing is that the observable object has to change his status to alert the observers and they update the data. But as i see is a forced implementation of the pattern. I suggest you to research more.

Comment: In BlackBerry only JavaME APIs are available, so this can't be done (but it might help to have a look at the javadocs anyway)